# which is better expression to make string into xml object[php]?

Tags: php, xml, constructor, simplexml

which is better expression to make string into xml object[php]?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_string);
```

vs

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're basically identical. [`SimpleXMLElement::__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) accepts data strings or file paths, if you set the appropriate options. `simplexml_load_file` and `simplexml_load_string` are basically convenience function wrappers that amount to the same thing as `new SimpleXMLElement()` with the correct options set.

Answer (score 2):

They're essentially the same. Which one you use is based on personal taste. I'd go for the first. The `simplexml_load_string` function will create an object too, which makes it essentially an alias for the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The `simplexml_load_string` lets you specify the class of which you want to get the object of. If you call the `simplexml_load_string` without specifying the class as second parameter, then it automatically gives you the object of `SimpleXMLElement`.

So, in the way you are running it, they both will give you same results.